# Blocking commits using svn and crucible until it get reviewed

Tags: svn, pre-commit, atlassian-crucible

Is there any possibility to block SVN commits until it get reviewed and approved by Atlassian Crucible code reviewers? I want to do something similar to Gerrit but using SVN. I heard that it can't be done with centralized control version systems, but is there some alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

Not out-of-the-box, but you probably could use an [SVN pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) on your SVN server, to query Crucible via REST and then either reject or approve the commit based on the criteria you define.

Disclosure: I'm a dev working on FishEye/Crucible

Comment: Is it possible to do with via branches? Like each developer has their own branch and then they would submit their change-set for review in Crucible, once the reviewer approved the change-set, only reviewer would have access to merge with the main branch.
Other devs then would need to regularly to GET from Main Branch.